# Play!Framework : using find() model method on a collection

Tags: java, collections, model, playframework, find

Let's assume a User class with theese fields :

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    public String email;
    public String password;
    @ElementCollection
    public List<String> stringList;
}
```

I am looking for a way to execute a database request to find all users that have a given string into their stringList, something like

```
List<User> usersHelloWorld = User.find("byStringList", "HelloWorld").fetch();
```

But of course, this doesn't work. Is there any way to make it work ?

**Edit :**

Here are my actual class fields :

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public String gender;
    public String fbId;
    public String googleId;
    @ElementCollection
    public List<String> eventTopicIds;
    @Transient
    UserEventBuffer eventBuffer;
    @Transient
    public String fbAccessToken;
    public String googleAccessToken;
}
```

With this request :

```
List<User> u = User.find("SELECT u from User u where ? IN u.eventTopicIds", "internalns_rootTopic1").fetch();
```

I get that error :

> **JPAQueryException occured :** Error while executing query SELECT u
>   from User u where ? IN u.eventTopicIds: Syntax error in SQL statement
>   "SELECT USER0_.ID AS ID3_, USER0_.EMAIL AS EMAIL3_, USER0_.FBID AS
>   FBID3_, USER0_.FIRSTNAME AS FIRSTNAME3_, USER0_.GENDER AS GENDER3_,
>   USER0_.GOOGLEACCESSTOKEN AS GOOGLEAC6_3_, USER0_.GOOGLEID AS
>   GOOGLEID3_, USER0_.LASTNAME AS LASTNAME3_, USER0_.PASSWORD AS
>   PASSWORD3_ FROM USER USER0_ CROSS JOIN USER_EVENTTOPICIDS EVENTTOPIC1_
>   WHERE USER0_.ID=EVENTTOPIC1_.USER_ID AND (? IN (.[*])) "; expected
>   "NOT, EXISTS, SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement: select user0_.id as id3_,
>   user0_.email as email3_, user0_.fbId as fbId3_, user0_.firstname as
>   firstname3_, user0_.gender as gender3_, user0_.googleAccessToken as
>   googleAc6_3_, user0_.googleId as googleId3_, user0_.lastname as
>   lastname3_, user0_.password as password3_ from User user0_ cross join
>   User_eventTopicIds eventtopic1_ where user0_.id=eventtopic1_.User_id
>   and (? in (.)) [42001-149]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you should be able to run a JPA query like

```
User.find("Select u from User as u inner join u.stringList as strings where ? in strings", "HelloWorld").fetch();
```

Did a small test, my object had emails instead of Strings, but it should be the same, unless you run into some reserved words. The problem was not the in keyword, I had to inner join the stringList in order to use the in keyword. A bit quick of the marker earlier:)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but JPA seems unhappy with the IN keyword I think, as to see the error message.

I edit my question to put the error message and my actual User class and request

Comment: I edited my response, I guess the above solution should work for you.